# Can't UnWrap Optional - None Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I assure you that i have checked all the answers prior posting this question on Unwrapping an object, but this thing simply does not seem to work for me. I am simply trying to pass on a text value from my cell tapped to the Label on the next screen.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if(segue.identifier == "detailViewSegue")
    {
        var DVC:DetailedViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailedViewController
        let path:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        var segueRecipeName:String = recipeMgr.RecipeName[path.row] as String
        DVC.detailedRecipeLabel.text = segueRecipeName
        } 
}
```

The problem occurs at this line -

```
DVC.detailedRecipeLabel.text = segueRecipeName //Can't UnWrap Optional - None
```

I know I'm supposed to check the nil value of segueRecipeName before assigning. I do a print check on the console and it clearly is not null. The error occurs only when I'm assigning the value to the 2nd view controller class object. I'm sure this will help others learning Swift :)

Comment: You haven't stated what "the problem" or "the error" is. add an error log or _something_.

Comment: Thanks Okuma, just edited my post.

Comment: what is `detailedRecipeLabel`? is that outlet connected properly?

Comment: Yes. @IBOutlet var detailedRecipeLabel: UILabel on DetailedViewController

Comment: Just as a general practice, modifying another view controllers views should be avoided to maintain consistency.  Set properties which the view controller itself can use to make it's own view content decisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DVC.detailedRecipeLabel` is `nil`

Probably it's a `IBOutlet` that hasn't been loaded yet.

You should add a custom property to your `DetailedViewController` that will accept your text, save it and then you can assign it to the label in `viewDidLoad`.

Example:

```
class DetailedViewController ... {
  ...
  var recipeName: NSString? = nil

  ...

  override func viewDidLoad() -> () {
     ...
     self.detailedRecipeLabel.text = self.recipeName
  }
}
```

```
DVC.recipeName = segueRecipeName
```

Comment: Thanks @Sulthan. So I just assigned the value of segueRecipeName to a variable on DetailedViewController and in the ViewLoad() method I reassigned the variable value to the Label (which i assume is loaded now) and it works fine. 
    DVC.detailedrecipeName = segueRecipeName

   and in ViewLoad()
   detailedRecipeLabel.text = detailedrecipeName

Is this the right way to do this? As I will have more values like Image that I would need to pass from the first view to the second.

Comment: @NarenSingh If you have more values to pass, maybe you should wrap them in a custom object and pass only that one object.